# Collection Datastructure in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, collections

Is there a `Collection` `DataStructure` available in `PHP` with `API` to add elements dynamically ?

Is `array` suitable for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP SPL provides quite a few [datastructures](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php) as well as the [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) which probably covers most of your requirements

Answer (score 1):

PHP is dynamically typed, so arrays should be flexible enough to do what you need here. You can use them to represent stacks, queues, hash tables, lists, etc.